# How to resolve this? "unfortunately <app> has stopped"

Tags: android, image, loops, android-intent, random

I can't figure out, the loop and randoms i cant see, the program will close directly.. and pop up  "unfortunately  has stopped"?

```
package com.main.project.spotddifference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private long startTime = 0L;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

Context context;
ImageView display,all;
TextView timer;
int anss,triesCount;

Random random = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
int next = random.nextInt( 23 ) + 1;

int[] imageViews = {R.id.A,R.id.B,R.id.C,R.id.D };

int[] img = new int[] {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6,R.drawable.img7,R.drawable.img8,
        R.drawable.img9,R.drawable.img10,R.drawable.img11,R.drawable.img12,
        R.drawable.img13,R.drawable.img14,R.drawable.img15,R.drawable.img16,
        R.drawable.img17,R.drawable.img18,R.drawable.img19,R.drawable.img20,
        R.drawable.img21,R.drawable.img22,R.drawable.img23,R.drawable.img24};

int [] ansLET = new int[] {R.drawable.alpha,R.drawable.charlie,R.drawable.alpha,R.drawable.delta,
        R.drawable.delta,R.drawable.alpha,R.drawable.beta,R.drawable.alpha,
        R.drawable.alpha,R.drawable.beta,R.drawable.delta,R.drawable.delta,
        R.drawable.charlie,R.drawable.alpha,R.drawable.charlie,R.drawable.alpha,
        R.drawable.beta,R.drawable.delta,R.drawable.charlie,R.drawable.alpha,
        R.drawable.beta,R.drawable.alpha,R.drawable.charlie,R.drawable.delta};

int [] ansImg = new int[]{R.drawable.aimg1,R.drawable.aimg2,R.drawable.aimg3,R.drawable.aimg4,
        R.drawable.aimg5,R.drawable.aimg6,R.drawable.aimg7,R.drawable.aimg8,
        R.drawable.aimg9,R.drawable.aimg10,R.drawable.aimg11,R.drawable.aimg12,
        R.drawable.aimg13,R.drawable.aimg14,R.drawable.aimg15,R.drawable.aimg16,
        R.drawable.aimg17,R.drawable.aimg18,R.drawable.aimg19,R.drawable.aimg20,
        R.drawable.aimg21,R.drawable.aimg22,R.drawable.aimg23,R.drawable.aimg24};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    display = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    context = this;
     allImage();
     allButton();
}

private void allButton() {
     Button choose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice);
     Button quit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

     choose.setOnClickListener(this);
     quit.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
    return true;
}



private void allImage() {
     ImageView a= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.A);
     ImageView b= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.B);
     ImageView c= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.C);
     ImageView d= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.D);

     a.setOnClickListener(this);
     b.setOnClickListener(this);
     c.setOnClickListener(this);
     d.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.A:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.alpha);
            break;
        case R.id.B:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.beta);
            break;
        case R.id.C:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.charlie);
            break;
        case R.id.D:
            display.setImageResource(R.drawable.delta);
            break;

        case R.id.choice:
            checkAns();
            break;
        case R.id.quit:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent (this,MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
    }
}

public void randomImage(){
    List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.length; i++) {
        int v = imageViews[i]-1;
        int vs = imageViews[i]-3;

        if ( generated.contains( next ) ) {
            generated.add( next );
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById( v );
            ImageView ivs = (ImageView) findViewById( vs );
            iv.setImageResource( img[next] );
            ivs.setImageResource(ansImg[next]);
            checkAns();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void checkAns(){
    for(int a = 1 ; a <= 2 ; a++){
        for(int s = 1 ; s <= 5; s++ ){
            if(((List<Integer>) display).contains(ansLET[next])){
            randomImage();
            }
            else{
                Intent in = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),AgainActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("result", "Congratulation!.You got the right answer!.");
                startActivity(in);
                break;
                }
            }
        Intent go = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),CongratsActivity.class);
        startActivity(go);
        }
    }

public void startTime(){
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}

public void pauseTime(){
    timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timer.setText("" + String.format("%02",mins) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};

}
```

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back"  >
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/A"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pics"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/B"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pics"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/C"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pics"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/D"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pics"
             />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom3"
        android:text="@string/btn_in_choose"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pics"
         />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="200" >

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom3"
        android:text="@string/btn_mainmenu"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="160"
        android:text="@string/heading_timer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:id="@+id/hm"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom3"
        android:text="@string/btn_in_hint"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat File:

```
09-17 22:45:22.828: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 7% free 2402K/2580K, paused 51ms, total 54ms
09-17 22:45:22.848: I/dalvikvm-heap(935): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.944MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-17 22:45:22.918: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3901K/4084K, paused 66ms, total 66ms
09-17 22:45:23.008: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3901K/4084K, paused 9ms+6ms, total 89ms
09-17 22:45:23.398: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3901K/4084K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
09-17 22:45:23.409: I/dalvikvm-heap(935): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.766MB for 864016-byte allocation
09-17 22:45:23.558: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 4745K/4928K, paused 89ms+5ms, total 147ms
09-17 22:45:23.558: D/dalvikvm(935): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
09-17 22:45:23.888: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1500K, 30% free 3946K/5628K, paused 6ms+57ms, total 171ms
09-17 22:45:24.108: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 697K, 36% free 3643K/5628K, paused 38ms, total 43ms
09-17 22:45:24.128: I/dalvikvm-heap(935): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.155MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-17 22:45:24.288: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 5142K/7132K, paused 154ms, total 155ms
09-17 22:45:24.428: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 28% free 5142K/7132K, paused 9ms+6ms, total 140ms
09-17 22:45:25.068: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 17% free 5986K/7132K, paused 73ms+89ms, total 267ms
09-17 22:45:25.158: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 9% free 4487K/4924K, paused 62ms, total 63ms
09-17 22:45:25.188: I/dalvikvm-heap(935): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.979MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-17 22:45:25.398: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 5987K/6428K, paused 74ms+46ms, total 211ms
09-17 22:45:25.908: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 27% free 5331K/7272K, paused 51ms, total 52ms
09-17 22:45:25.908: I/dalvikvm-heap(935): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.804MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-17 22:45:26.128: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 6831K/7272K, paused 72ms+6ms, total 201ms
09-17 22:45:26.688: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 24% free 6175K/8116K, paused 62ms, total 62ms
09-17 22:45:26.688: I/dalvikvm-heap(935): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.628MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-17 22:45:26.898: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 7675K/8116K, paused 75ms+28ms, total 202ms
09-17 22:45:27.439: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 22% free 7020K/8960K, paused 50ms, total 51ms
09-17 22:45:27.639: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 8520K/8960K, paused 71ms+22ms, total 185ms
09-17 22:45:28.129: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 20% free 7864K/9804K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
09-17 22:45:28.609: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 9364K/9804K, paused 43ms, total 44ms
09-17 22:45:28.738: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 19% free 8708K/10648K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
09-17 22:45:29.198: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 10208K/10648K, paused 45ms, total 46ms
09-17 22:45:29.318: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 17% free 9553K/11492K, paused 40ms, total 46ms
09-17 22:45:29.808: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 11053K/11492K, paused 66ms, total 66ms
09-17 22:45:29.948: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 16% free 10397K/12336K, paused 52ms, total 53ms
09-17 22:45:30.398: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 11897K/12336K, paused 56ms, total 57ms
09-17 22:45:30.518: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 15% free 11241K/13180K, paused 48ms, total 49ms
09-17 22:45:30.958: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 12741K/13180K, paused 51ms, total 52ms
09-17 22:45:31.268: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:31.298: D/gralloc_goldfish(935): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-17 22:45:36.348: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:36.458: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:36.588: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:36.808: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:38.178: D/dalvikvm(935): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1507K, 14% free 12737K/14644K, paused 158ms, total 187ms
09-17 22:45:39.329: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 2407 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:39.988: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 620 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:40.748: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 703 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:41.048: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 285 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:43.338: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:43.908: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:44.338: I/Choreographer(935): Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:48.948: D/AndroidRuntime(935): Shutting down VM
09-17 22:45:48.948: W/dalvikvm(935): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935): java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: 02
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:2304)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.advance(Formatter.java:2298)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseConversionType(Formatter.java:2377)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseWidth(Formatter.java:2360)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseArgumentIndexAndFlags(Formatter.java:2344)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.parseFormatToken(Formatter.java:2281)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1069)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1040)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1009)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1988)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1962)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at com.main.project.spotddifference.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:196)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 22:45:52.828: I/Process(935): Sending signal. PID: 935 SIG: 9
09-17 22:45:53.808: E/Trace(972): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-17 22:45:54.478: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 41K, 8% free 2402K/2584K, paused 139ms, total 176ms
09-17 22:45:54.578: I/dalvikvm-heap(972): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.944MB for 1536016-byte allocation
09-17 22:45:54.748: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3901K/4088K, paused 169ms, total 169ms
09-17 22:45:54.948: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3901K/4088K, paused 15ms+26ms, total 199ms
09-17 22:45:56.298: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 3901K/4088K, paused 238ms, total 238ms
09-17 22:45:56.358: I/dalvikvm-heap(972): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.766MB for 864016-byte allocation
09-17 22:45:56.618: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 4745K/4932K, paused 74ms+35ms, total 258ms
09-17 22:45:57.848: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1500K, 31% free 3872K/5560K, paused 140ms, total 170ms
09-17 22:45:58.218: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_CONCURRENT freed 625K, 34% free 3704K/5560K, paused 6ms+6ms, total 228ms
09-17 22:45:58.588: D/dalvikvm(972): GC_CONCURRENT freed 291K, 32% free 3805K/5560K, paused 77ms+33ms, total 174ms
09-17 22:45:58.868: I/Choreographer(972): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:45:58.899: D/gralloc_goldfish(972): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-17 22:46:13.848: I/Choreographer(972): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-17 22:46:14.098: D/AndroidRuntime(972): Shutting down VM
09-17 22:46:14.118: W/dalvikvm(972): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo    {com.main.project.spotddifference/com.main.project.spotddifference.HelpActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID     #0x7f090014 type #0x12 is not valid
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090014 type #0x12 is not valid
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2144)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.main.project.spotddifference.HelpActivity.onCreate(HelpActivity.java:17)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-17 22:46:14.368: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  ... 11 more
09-17 22:46:16.808: I/Process(972): Sending signal. PID: 972 SIG: 9
```

this is my codes , please help me out off this problem.

Comment: Or to put it another way: here is a bunch of source code. I'm not going to tell you what it does, how it does it or anything else useful. It doesn't work (but I won't give you any clues about how when or why it stops). Perhaps you should try a debugger?

Comment: The question should be specific so that other can understand.  This is merely a copy paste pf code without mentioning the specific problem.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmon, your own logcat clearly answers your question.  This is actually a wonderful clear exception message your are getting, don't under appreciate that:

```
09-17 22:45:49.108: E/AndroidRuntime(935): 
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: 
Conversion: 02
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely `R.java` not being regenerated or you have an error in your XML which the IDE can't detect. In any case, the following line in the error log can help: `Resource ID #0x7f090014 type #0x12 is not valid`

Open your `R.java` file and try to find the variable that has that value set to it by the Java compiler. The variable name corresponds to an element in your XML files. Try to find the element and check if its XML file isn't broken.

As a last resort, begin rebuilding your XML files one by one, tag by tag until you find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The logcat shows:

This means that it is some problem with some formatter string, so check:

String.format("%02",mins) and make it with "%02d" and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

You probably are freezing the II thread by heavy work. Take some time and implement threads using AsyncTask